# errno set in child process after fork - OSX

Tags: c, macos, unix, fork, errno

here's a weird thing I found today on Mac OSX.

After a fork, which has succeeded, errno is set at 0
in the father's process (as expected), but set at 22 in the child process.
Here's the source-code :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int nbArgs, char** args){
   int pid;
   errno = 0;
   printf("Errno value before the call to fork : %d.\n", errno);
   if ((pid = fork()) == -1){
      perror("Fork failed.");
      exit(1);
   }
   if (pid == 0){
      printf("Child : errno value : %d.\n", errno);
   }else{
      printf("Father : pid value : %d ; errno value : %d.\n", pid, errno);
      wait(NULL);
   }
   exit(0);
}
```

And the execution track :

```
Remis-Mac:TP3 venant$ ./errno_try
Errno value before the call to fork : 0.
Father : pid value : 9526 ; errno value : 0.
Child : errno value : 22.
```

As far as I know, and according to the [Opengroup specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html),
"The new process (child process) shall be an exact copy of the calling process (parent process) except as detailed below [...]", including the value of the global variable errno -_-

Does anyone have a clue to explain that undesired behavior ?

Comment: It's not especially undesirable.  Most successful system calls don't bother to set errno and errno can be a macro and is thread specific.

Comment: You're right Duck, it isn't undesirable, but that behavior can be misleading sometimes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curious...I can reproduce the problem on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks with GCC 4.8.2 and with Clang.

POSIX says that some functions that fail will set `errno` (and [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) is one of those functions), but does not say that functions that succeed will not set `errno`.  For example, on Solaris, many standard I/O functions set `errno` if the output stream is not a terminal. However, resetting `errno = 0;` after the `printf()` doesn't alter the behaviour on Mac OS X.

#### POSIX 2008 (System Interfaces — General Information: 3. [Error numbers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_03)):

> Some functions provide the error number in a variable accessed through the symbol `errno`, defined by including the `<errno.h>` header. The value of `errno` should only be examined when it is indicated to be valid by a function's return value. No function in this volume of POSIX.1-2008 shall set `errno` to zero. For each thread of a process, the value of `errno` shall not be affected by function calls or assignments to `errno` by other threads.

If `fork()` failed, then `errno` would be set to indicate the failure. When it succeeds, it is not technically valid to inspect `errno`.  And this is a demonstration of why.

Answer (score 1):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) says:

> Upon successful completion, fork() shall return 0 to the child process and shall return the process ID of the child process to the parent process. Both processes shall continue to execute from the fork() function. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned to the parent process, no child process shall be created, and errno shall be set to indicate the error.

which means `errno` is specified to be set on success only. Otherwise nothing is specified, so you can expect an old value of `errno` or any unspecified value.

Comment: But the old value of `errno` was 0 and the value after the fork in the child is 22, which is curious since `errno` is also copied when the process as a whole is copied.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler as you said in your answer there is nothing that prevents `fork` to set `errno` to `0` on success as the value is then  unspecified.

Comment: There is a mandate in POSIX that functions _never_ set `errno` to 0 — see the quote I've added.