# fork + wait gets EINTR on OSX

Tags: c, macos, unix, fork

I fail at fork 101. I expect this to fork a child process, and output both child and parent printfs:

```
pid_t fpid;

if ((fpid = fork()) < 0)
{
    printf("fork: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(-1);
}

if (0 == fpid) // child
{
    printf("\nI am the child\n");
}
else
{
    printf("\nI am the parent\n");
    pid_t wpid;
    while ((wpid = waitpid(WAIT_ANY, NULL, 0)))
    {
        if (errno == ECHILD)
            break;
        else if (wpid < 0)
            printf("wait: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

Instead, I get this output:

> I am the parent
>
> wait: Interrupted system call

So my question is: why doesn't the child get a chance to live and run? Won't someone please think of the children! Also, where does the EINTR come from? Obviously, this is somehow related to my first question.

Furthermore, when I run that code in a standalone program, it works correctly, but not when inside a larger program of mine; what could the larger program do to upset waitpid?

FWIW this is on OSX 10.9.

Comment: Doesn't the child send a SIGCHLD? Maybe block that signal?

Comment: Weird, it works on my Linux machine. I don't know much about OSX... does it have some kind of sandboxing thing or require special application permissions to execute `fork()`?

Comment: Works fine on FreeBSD, which is a close relative of OSX.

Comment: I'm not using SIGCHLD anywhere explicitly, but I am using setjmp(), could that be related?

Comment: What is the value in `wpid` after `waitpid()`? If it is not -1, then you are not entitled to look at `errno`.  See [`errno` set in child process after `fork()` in Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295011/errno-set-in-child-process-after-fork-osx/) for a related scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On OSX, it's not legal to do much on the child side of a fork before/without execing. See the caveat at the bottom of the [fork man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fork.2.html). The list of safe functions is on the [sigaction(2) man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sigaction.2.html). `printf()` is not among them.

Also, stdout is likely buffered. The results of the `printf()` may not be being flushed. It would be flushed if you called `exit()`, but that's also not legal on the child side of a fork. (It's appropriate to use `_exit()` but that doesn't flush open streams.) As it is, you don't appear to be exiting your child process, which means flow of execution continues to the caller of the code you've shown, presumably returning to the rest of your program. It may be getting stuck there because of the limitations on the child side of a fork.

You may have more luck if you do something like this in the child:

```
const char msg[] = "\nI am the child\n";
write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg) - 1);
_exit(0);
```

Finally, I think you should pass `fpid` rather than `WAIT_ANY` to `waitpid()`. You have a specific child process you want to wait for. In the context of a larger program, you don't want to steal the notification of the termination of a child spawned by some other subcomponent. And you always need to loop around interruptible syscalls until they return something other than `EINTR`.

Comment: So that caveat says "In this situation it is reasonable to exec yourself", which is what I would need to do. How do I know what to pass into exec to indicate "myself", if the app isn't necessarily in the working directory?

Comment: Given that you're on OS X, you can use [`_NSGetExecutablePath()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dyld.3.html). If you're using Cocoa, you can use `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath] fileSystemRepresentation]`. You would have to call those before the fork, though. And, of course, when you exec yourself, you'll need to pass a special argument to let the new process know not to run the app as normal. If the app is bundled and/or linked to AppKit, the child process may get a separate Dock icon, which you wouldn't want.

Comment: @Gilles, the restriction is part of the POSIX spec. It's also common sense. When you fork, only the thread calling `fork()` survives into the child process. The others simply vanish. Those other threads may have been holding shared resources such as locks inside of the system libraries. Therefore, calling any non-async-cancel-safe routines is prone to locking up or finding the internal data structures in inconsistent state.

Comment: @KenThomases On most unices, this only applies to multithreaded programs. Otherwise, on traditional unix systems, `fork` makes a copy of the process, and it doesn't matter what happens next. There are other possible nast effects, such as stdio buffers being duplicated, but there's no requirement to avoid certain library functions after a `fork` in a single-threaded program.

Comment: @Gilles, but there's no guarantee that a program is single-threaded just because the application code didn't create any other threads. System libraries can use threads for their own purposes. Effectively, you must assume that all programs are multi-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

Only check `errno` if a failure was indicated, for example by a system call returning `-1`.

The code should look like this:

```
pid_t fpid;

if ((fpid = fork()) < 0)
{
    printf("fork: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(-1);
}

if (0 == fpid) // child
{
    printf("\nI am the child\n");
}
else
{
    printf("\nI am the parent\n");

    pid_t wpid;
    while ((wpid = waitpid(WAIT_ANY, NULL, 0)))
    {
        if (-1 == wpid)
        {
            perror("waitpid() failed");
        }
        else if (wpid == fpid)
        {
            /* My child ended, so stop waiting for it. */
            break;
        }
    }
}
```