# Why does fork() return errno = 22

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I have a simple program that goes like this :-

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
  printf ("Before Fork [%d][%d:%s]\n",getpid(),errno,strerror(errno));
  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (!pid) //CHILD PROCESS
  {
    printf ("In Child Process [%d  [%d:%s]\n",getpid(),errno,strerror(errno));
  }
  else 
  {
   while(1);
  }
}
```

This produces the output :-

```
Before Fork [50083][0:Undefined error: 0]
In Child Process [50084][22:Invalid argument]
```

Does anyone know why the OS throws INVALID ARGUMENT error immediately after FORK ?

Comment: [You're not alone in your observation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295011/errno-set-in-child-process-after-fork-osx). That selected answer holds true for you as well. If `fork()` succeeded, there is no specific value to be set in `errno`; only when it *failed* can you rely on it harboring a reason.

Comment: Tomorrow could be 33

Comment: If in doubt always read the relevant man page. In this case the [errno man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno): "Its value is significant **only when the return value of the call indicated an error**"

Comment: what operating system are you running?

Comment: @everyone :- As WhozCraig and michi mentioned, since fork works (doesn't return -1), we cannot (rather should not) work on the errno value.

Comment: @unixmiah that would be the OS in the tags list; Linux, not that it matters here.

Comment: @WhozCraig it does.

Answer (score -1):

This is just a guess, but it may be because fork becomes the syscall clone() (looking at an strace):

```
6952  write(1, "Before Fork [6952][0:Success]\n", 30) = 30
6952  clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f55f10e19d0) = 6953
6953  write(1, "In Child Process [6953  [0:Succe"..., 36) = 36
```

And clone(2) manpage says:

> EINVAL Returned  by  clone()  when  a  zero  value  is  specified
>   for child_stack.

I didn't walk through the kernel code, but perhaps something is setting the errno because of `child_stack=0` but finishing the child creation without erroring out because the flags.

Then again.... strace could be screwed up because there is no way a SIGCHLD belongs as a clone flag.

Comment: No. It's Undefined Behaviour to use `errno` unless the preceding function call failed (which it did not in this case).

Comment: I didn't say it was defined in a spec. I was looking into the cause. Something changed errno and the only suspects seem to be the writes and the clone. I don't think it was the writes.